# Authentication that immune to cookie hijacking

Tags: authentication, cookies, session-management

There is a website that uses a cookie to store the user’s session info. Let's assume that a hacker steals a user’s cookie to gain unauthorized access to their online accounts via some vulnerability.
How backend service can prevent such kind of attacks even if a session cookie become known to a hacker?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What protects a JWT from being hijacked and used to pose as the original user?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/170599/what-protects-a-jwt-from-being-hijacked-and-used-to-pose-as-the-original-user). In short: a) protect the cookie against sniffing in the first place b) bind the cookie to the device, environment etc so that it cannot be used on different devices, environments ...

Comment: Cookie hijacking or session hijacking? Tokens can also be stored in LocalStorage.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the cited article, you need to manage the auth token life cycle properly.  Decide if you want a cookie, be it jwt or not, to persist beyond one user session. Use expirations. Also, you need to manage authenticated users on the backend in memory or a DB, delete them as cookies expire or users logout.  Create a small attack surface.